# How to embed a google analytics script (new version) on a seaside app

Tags: javascript, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, seaside

I implemented at the way of use a FileLibrary.

Then I've the following code:

updateRoot: anHtmlRoot

```
super updateRoot: anHtmlRoot.
anHtmlRoot title: self title.
anHtmlRoot link beShortcutIcon; url: MyfileLibrary  / #myGraphicPng.
anHtmlRoot javascript url: (MyFileLibrary urlOf: #analyticsJs)
```

Google check the page ok, but never I get real numbers, allways is in the state of "awaiting data".

Any hint or example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics works well with Seaside. I've been using it for years on many (mostly Pier based) Seaside sites.

1. Make sure that `#analyticsJs` contains the correct Google Analytics tracking code. It is much more efficient (and suggested by Google) to inline the code into the script tag, but I assume it also works using an URL.
2. Make sure that your application is running on a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). I assume that the tracker does not work on `localhost`, see [Google Analytics Help](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55510) for more information.

Comment: Hi Lukas: 1. I'm sure the code is ok (Triple checked). About inline I tried some ways but seems not be effective neither. Any tip
to use script tag properly?
2. Yes, I'm trying in a proper FQDN.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly more complicated (verbatim) example to support multiple trackers (to CC tracking data to client's account, for example), custom variables and URL generation:

updateRoot: root

```
super updateRoot: root.
root javascript with: (String streamContents: [:ws | self renderAnalyticsOn: ws]).
```

renderAnalyticsOn: stream

```
| options |
options := OrderedCollection new.
self trackingConfiguration keysAndValuesDo: 
        [:tracker :accountid |
        | isForClient |
        isForClient := tracker notEmpty.
        options add: (Array with: tracker , '_setAccount' with: accountid).
        isForClient
            ifTrue: 
                [options
                    add: (Array with: tracker , '_setDomainName' with: 'none');
                    add: (Array with: tracker , '_setAllowLinker' with: true);
                    add: (Array with: tracker , '_setAllowHash' with: false)].
        self trackingCustomVariables do: 
                [:array |
                array at: 1 put: tracker , array first.
                options add: array].
        options add: (Array with: tracker , '_trackPageview' with: '/' , self trackingURL)].
stream
    nextPutAll: 'var _gaq = _gaq || [];';
    nextPutAll: '_gaq.push('.
options do: [:ea | stream json: ea] separatedBy: [stream nextPut: $,].
stream nextPutAll: ');'.
stream
    nextPutAll: '(function() {';
    nextPutAll: 'var ga = document.createElement(''script''); ga.type = ''text/javascript''; ga.async = true;';
    nextPutAll: 'ga.src = (''https:'' == document.location.protocol ? ''https://ssl'' : ''http://www'') + ''.google-analytics.com/ga.js'';';
    nextPutAll: 'var s = document.getElementsByTagName(''script'')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);';
    nextPutAll: '})();'.
```

trackingConfiguration

```
| trackers |
trackers := (Dictionary new)
            at: '' put: 'UA-XXXX-YY';
            yourself.
self session googleAnalytics ifNotNil: [:v | trackers at: 'b.' put: v].
^trackers.
```

trackingCustomVariables

```
^Array with: (Array
                with: '_setCustomVar'
                with: 1
                with: 'Application'
                with: self class applicationName
                with: 2).
```

trackingURL

```
^String streamContents: [:ws | crumbs do: [:ea | ws nextPutAll: ea title asAnalyticsURL] separatedBy: [ws nextPut: $/]].
```

asAnalyticsURL

```
^self asLowercase copyReplace: Character space with: $_
```

Comment: mm, need to try this approach. Thanks.

Comment: Tried, some short notes may be because I'm not familiar with your style of programming: 1. #trackingURL what is crumbs? 2. I'm not using session here, then simply I eliminated, right? 3. Replaced #copyReplace:with: by #copyReplacedAll:with:.

Comment: Like I said, this was taken directly from our application, so: 'crumbs' is a variable where a stack of components represents one's navigational state and is used to render proper URL for GA; session is used to allow clients to provide an extra GA account identifier; in VisualWorks copyReplace:with: replaces all occurrences of arg1 with arg2, the *All: flavor is used to replace sub-collections.

Comment: Thanks by the explanations. I changed my code at this (aproximate) way and now when the page load I think that GA is working. Will see in 24 hours if the GA page show anything.
But still wondering why the FileLibrary approach don't works :(

Comment: Yes, worked at this way, thanks by the hints.

Anyway is very strange why don't works using a FileLibrary.